# Getting data posted in between two dates

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

How can I retrieve data from the database by querying records between two dates using CodeIgniter's activerecord?

Comment: please explain further, and if you have tried anything, please post the code.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: Are you trying to pull data from your database between two dates?

Comment: yes I am trying to pull data from my database between two dates using codeigniter quries

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This looks like what you need:

```
$this->db->where('order_date >=', $first_date);
$this->db->where('order_date <=', $second_date);
return $this->db->get('orders');
```

Comment: @ThorpeObazee what if i have two number and want to that entered number is in between or not?

Answer (score 12):

Try This:

```
$this->db->where('sell_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 6):

This worked great for me

```
$this->db->where('sell_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
```

Answer (score 6):

if your date filed is timestamp into database then this is the easy way to get record

```
$this->db->where('DATE(RecordDate) >=', date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate)));
$this->db->where('DATE(RecordDate) <=', date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate)));
```

Comment: Using DATE function in where clauses causes your indexing to fail. Then you have to bear performance issues.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
$this->db->where('RecordDate >=', '2018-08-17 00:00:00');
$this->db->where('RecordDate <=', '2018-10-04 05:32:56');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare SQL dates, you can try this:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where(' date_columnname >= date("'.$from.'")');
$this->db->where( 'date_columnname <= date("'.$to.'")');
```

That worked for me (PHP and MySQL).

Answer (score 2):

Just simply write BETWEEN `'{$startDate}' AND '{$endDate}'`  in where condition
as

```
->where("date BETWEEN '{$startDate}' AND '{$endDate}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

May this helpful to you.... 
With Join of Three Tables

```
public function get_details_beetween_dates()
    {
        $from = $this->input->post('fromdate');
        $to = $this->input->post('todate');

        $this->db->select('users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, groups.name as designation, dailyinfo.amount as Total_Fine, dailyinfo.date as Date_of_Fine, dailyinfo.desc as Description')
                    ->from('users')
                    ->where('dailyinfo.date >= ',$from)
                    ->where('dailyinfo.date <= ',$to)
                    ->join('users_groups','users.id = users_groups.user_id')
                    ->join('dailyinfo','users.id = dailyinfo.userid')
                    ->join('groups','groups.id = users_groups.group_id');

        /*
        $this->db->select('date, amount, desc')
                 ->from('dailyinfo')
                 ->where('dailyinfo.date >= ',$from)
                 ->where('dailyinfo.date <= ',$to);
        */

        $q = $this->db->get();

        $array['userDetails'] = $q->result();
        return $array;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->db
              ->get_where('orders',array('order_date <='=>$first_date,'order_date >='=>$second_date))
              ->result_array();
```

Comment: I feel like the `<=` and `>=` might be the wrong way around, but I don't know what values they actually hold.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to force using BETWEEN keyword on Codeigniter query helper. You can use where without escape false like this code. Works well on CI version 3.1.5.  Hope its help someone.

```
if(!empty($tglmin) && !empty($tglmax)){
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->where('DATE(create_date) BETWEEN "'.$tglmin.'" AND "'.$tglmax.'"', '',false);
        $this->db->group_end();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DATETIME datatype then you can use:

```
$this->db->where('order_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date.' 00:00:00')). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end_date.' 23:59:59')).'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = $this->input->post('startDate');
$end_date  = $this->input->post('endDate');
    
$data['total_retailer'] = $this->company_model->where(
                    array(
                        'DATE(company_created_date) >=' => $start_date,
                        'DATE(company_created_date) <=' => $end_date,
                    )
                )
```