# codeigniter : getting data between two dates in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to retrieve data between two dates in mysql.

from date : `01/04/2015` 
to date : `01/05/2015`

but i cant get date these in single variable;

how i am get as below mentioned:

```
$fdate=01;
$fmonth=04;
$tdate=01;
$tmonth=05;
$year=2015;
```

my code in model :

```
function date_range($fdate,$fmonth,$tdate,$tmonth,$year)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where('DAY(order_date) >=',$fdate);
            $this->db->where('MONTH(order_date) >=',$fmonth);
            $this->db->where('YEAR(order_date) >=',$year);
            $this->db->where('DAY(order_date) <=',$tdate);
            $this->db->where('MONTH(order_date) <=',$tmonth);
            $this->db->where('YEAR(order_date) <=',$year);
            return $this->db->get('orders');
        }
```

some times it return results properly, and some times it not return result, but i had an data in `mysql` between mentioned two dates.

what mistake i make on this code please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875668/codeigniter-getting-data-posted-in-between-two-dates

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
$this->db->where("YOUR COLUMN BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(COLUMN1,'%d/%m/%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(COLUMN2,'%d/%m/%Y'"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use CodeIgniter:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
```

where your `"Your QUERY"` will contain mysql `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')`

For example using [Query Binding](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table 
       WHERE order_date between  DATE_FORMAT(? ? ?,'%d %m %Y') 
                             AND DATE_FORMAT(? ? ?,'%d %m %Y')"; 

$this->db->query($sql, array($fdate, $fmonth, year, $tdate, $tmonth, year));
```

Comment: Charlesliam ! i cant understand properly pls give another example

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
function date_range($fdate,$fmonth,$tdate,$tmonth,$year)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where('order_date <=',date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$fmonth,$fdate,$year)))
            $this->db->where('order_date >=',date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$tmonth,$tdate,$year)))
            return $this->db->get('orders');
        }
```

Comment: In `where` condition it cant get given date if taken `default date` as `1970-01-01`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function get_between_dates($date_from, $date_to)
{
    $this->db->where('order_date >=', $date_from);
    $this->db->where('order_date <=', $date_to);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

This is how you can get data between two dates. Name your form inputs as `date_from` and `date_to` respectively.